# React: What is the core difference between setting a state in a constructor vs. just setting the state within the class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

What is the core difference here? I have used both in similar ways with success. But what is happening behind the scenes that makes them different and when should each approach be used?

```
class Store extends React.Component { 
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state =  {
      checked: false
    }
}
```

vs.

```
class Store extends React.Component { 
  state = { checked: false }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no "should" for those two methods. Your second example is a new proposal: [class-fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields). This is it. So, if you don't need to use the `constructor`, you can skip it and define your `state`, also the class methods if you need them, like your second example.

You need Babel and a [specific plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties) to use this new proposal. Since you can use it successfully, this means you already have this plugin. Behind the scenes your second code is compiled into something like this:

```
class Store extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    var _temp;

    return (_temp = super(...args)), (this.state = { checked: false }), _temp;
  }
}
```